# Will I lose all my saved games if I start a new campaign in Rage?

Tags: rage

I'm part way through a game of Rage and if I go to Campaign->New Game now, I get the following warning:

[image]

Does this mean I will lose all my saved games for the current campaign or does it only apply to the current campaign progress and my ability to keep playing by choosing "Continue Campaign" from the menu?

Comment: I would totally test this out, except if I'm not done with Rage by the time Arkham City comes out, it may not get played again until 2012.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quick answer is **no**, you will not lose your saved games. What you will lose is your current auto-save, as can be seen by the following screenshot:

[image: Dead autosave]

You can see that while I am at the game's very beginning, which is where the current autosave is, I still have my saved games from a later stage.

When you choose "Continue Campaign" from the main menu, what the game does is load your auto-save. When I loaded one of my later saves and got to the point where the game auto-saved, continuing the campaign loaded that save, instead of putting me at the beginning (where I ended up until I did that).

Comment: So loading your older campaign and hitting the autosave point will effectively "switch you back" to that campaign?

Comment: @AnnaLear: Correct.